# Azure sponsorships is active but in the azure portal tell that not supscription

Tags: azure, azureportal

I Have activated the subscription for the student account in azure, and it is activated in the sponsorship.
[image]

But in azure portal is
[image]

I don't know why is it, please help me...

Comment: You will need to contact Azure Support for this. From your 1st screenshot, it is clear that there is no subscription associated with the sponsorship.

Answer (score 0):

As the 1st image shows that there are **`0 active subscriptions`** associated with the sponsorship.

[image]

#### How to provision an Azure Sponsorship Subscription

1. Navigate to **https://www.microsoftazurepass.com/** to register with provided Azure sponsorship offer code where you have to use a Microsoft Account or personal MSA or Microsoft 365 Account.
2. Note this point, **`only this account`** used to register the sponsorship offer which is able to manage/view your subscription consumption and remaining credits.
3. After your membership has been activated, you will be alerted that you have `90 days` and `X number of credits` to use, and that the subscription will be terminated after `90 days` or after your `credits` have been used up, whichever comes first. If you want to keep using the **`subscription`**, you'll have to switch to pay as you go billing and enter credit card information.
4. If you are the original user who registered the Azure sponsorship offer code, go to https://www.microsoftazuresponsorships.com/ and log in with your credentials to see how much of your subscription has been used and how much credit you have left.

If your subscription fails to activate which means inactive state or shows 0 subscriptions, contact the [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) for a better resolution.